# Sequence limit!!

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Hi I have a question about a proof of limit. In my text book, there is an example to prove $\lim \frac{n^2+3}{n+1}=+\infty$. The definition of a diverge sequence is as follows.
$$\forall M>0, \exists N\  s.t \ n>N\ \Rightarrow\  s_n > M$$
The proof in the book tries to bound the sequence below by some multiple of $\frac{n^2}{n}=n$. so it makes the numerator smaller and the denominator larger which makes the whole expression $\frac{n^2+3}{n+1}$ smaller. The proof in the book says $\frac{n^2+3}{n+1} > \frac{n^2}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}n$, and it suffices to arrange for $\frac{1}{2}n > M$. But How do we sure that $\frac{1}{2}n > M$? I thought I have to find some expression that is greater than $\frac{n^2+3}{n+1}$ so I can make sure that the expression is greater than any $M$.

Comment: Pick your $M$ and then your $n>2M$... you want $\frac{n^2+3}{n+1}$ bigger than anything not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little explanation for the expression the book gave. Note that:

$$n^2 + 3 > n^2\text{ for all natural numbers}$$

$$n+1 \leq 2n \text{ for all natural numbers}$$

Now we have the fraction: $\frac{n^2 + 3}{n+1}$. As you said if we make the numerator smaller the new fraction will be smaller than the initial one. Also if we make the denominator larger we'll get the same effect. So we'll both things. So we have:

$$\frac{n^2 + 3}{n+1} > \frac{n^2}{n+1} \geq \frac{n^2}{2n} = \frac{n}{2}$$

Because $n$ approaches infinity that means that $ \frac{n}{2}$ will also approach infinity. And because the initial fraction is greater than $ \frac{n}{2}$ it means that as $n$ approaches infinity it value will also approach infinity.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{n^2+3}{n+1}=\frac{(n^2-1)+4}{n+1}=n-1+\frac4{n+1}\gt n-1
$$